# HSQLDB: Easy way to have all created files deleted after closing connection?

Tags: csv, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I have an app/tool which reads from a CSV file and writes to another, processing it using HSQLDB.

I want to have the CSV file as the only output, and the database files should disappear after the process finishes.

- I tried to use *mem* storage, but that prevents HSQLDB to write to the CSV file.
- I also tried to DROP SCHEMA before closing the connection, but that does not remove the files.
- I don't like deleting the files manually, as that's HSQLDB implementation-specific and can change over time.

Is there some systemic way to leave only the CSV file?
Ideally, I'd like some option which would allow HSQLDB to write CSV file while using in-memory storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB never deletes its own files. You can reduce the number of files by using

SET FILES LOG FALSE